# how to get one by one column name using loop is SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to fetch column names of the table using loop so that I can create automated 'insert' (from one database to another) just like the attached image
[image].

Main purpose is that I want to enter table name and script should generate the insert just like the attached image.

this is the table structure

[image: table_structure]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

My response is too long to be a comment, so I needed to put it as answer.

1. Using a loop for this is actually the worst idea ever. Approaching SQL like a normal programming language can lead to bad habits.
2. There are system tables that store all of this information for you. You should look at sys.columns and sys.tables. There are obvious joins between these two tables that will get you 90% of the way there, if not all the way.
3. Youre working way too hard to achieve what is a pretty common task - simple ETL of one object to another destination. Im pretty much of this work youre doing to create inserts probably can just be simple inserts without having to check if the values being null or not (nulls can be inserted from select statements). Youre most certainly creating unnecessary overhead in this approach (granted im just guessing, but from the looks of it you have 110k rows with conditional logic running per row, so I dont think Im wrong here). My suggestion is to read an article or two about ETL best standard practices and learn what an "UpSert" is.

Answer (score -1):

This should get you about 90% there...

```
 Declare @sql varchar(max) = ''

 select @sql = @sql + '(Case when ' + c.name + ' IS NULL then ''NULL'' 
 Else Concat('''''''''+ ',' + c.name +''''''',  '') end ), '
 from sys.columns c
 inner join sys.tables t on c.object_id = t.object_id
 where c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.Account')


 Select ' insert into dbo.Account ('  + @sql + ')'
 print @sql
 --EXEC (@sql)
```